Going to momentum space from Hamiltonian equation 17.4 chapter 17 in Schwartz
I'm reading the chapter 17 on the anomalous magnetic moment in QFT and the SM (Schwartz).
In the section "17.1 Extracting the moment" he says
"Going to momentum space,the Dirac equation implies
\begin{equation}
\frac{(H-eA_0)^2}{2m}\psi=\Big(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{(\vec p -e\vec A)^2}{2m}-2\frac{e}{2m}\vec B \cdot \vec S \pm i \frac{e}{m}\vec E \cdot \vec S\Big)\psi,\tag{17.4}
\end{equation}
Could you me explain what he doing here?

Your equation, (17.4), follows from (17.2) & (17.3), yielding (10.109), and transforming its gradients into $(H,\vec p)$ in Fourier transforming. It is a plugin: show your work!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation

could you write me the various steps? Thanks !@CosmasZachos @Andrew
